# fasttext train_supervised model: get top predicted labels

Tags: python, nlp, fasttext

I have used fasttext train_supervised utility to train a  classification model according to their webpage https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html .

```
model = fasttext.train_supervised(input='train.txt', autotuneValidationFile='validation.txt', autotuneDuration=600)
```

After I got the model how could I explore what kind of best parameters for the model like in sklearn after  a set of best parameters trained, we could always check the values for these parameters but I could not find any document to explain this.

I also used this trained model to make prediction on my data

```
model.predict(test_df.iloc[2, 1])
```

It will return the label with a probability like this

```
(('__label__2',), array([0.92334366]))
```

I'm wondering if I have 5 labels, every time when make prediction,is it possible for each  text to  get  all the probability for each label?
Like  for the above test_df text,
I could get something like

```
model.predict(test_df.iloc[2, 1])

(('__label__2',), array([0.92334366])),(('__label__1',), array([0.82334366])),
(('__label__3',), array([0.52333333])),(('__label__0',), array([0.07000000])),
(('__label__4',), array([0.00002000]))
```

could find anything related to make change to get such prediction results.
Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html#advanced-readers-precision-and-recall) in the documentation, when using `predict` method, you should specify `k` parameter to get the top-k predicted classes.

`model.predict("Why not put knives in the dishwasher?", k=5)`

**OUTPUT:**

```
((u'__label__food-safety', u'__label__baking', u'__label__equipment',
u'__label__substitutions', u'__label__bread'), array([0.0857 , 0.0657,
0.0454, 0.0333, 0.0333]))
```